# Pandas: pivot_table unique count returns count

Tags: python, pandas, unique, pivot-table

I'm writing several pivot tables using pandas. For many of them, I need to return unique values. In a two-dimensional pivot table, the below code works as it should. When I add a third dimension, the code returns the count rather than the unique count. I suspect this has something to do with the aggfunc, but can't determine to what it should be changed.

Code is below:

```
data = pd.read_csv('scrubbed_data.csv', usecols = ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3'])
cd1 = pd.tools.pivot.pivot_table(data = data, values = 'col_2', index = 'col_1', columns = 'col_3', aggfunc=lambda x: len(x.unique()))
cd1.to_csv('pivot.csv')
```

Below is a mock-up of the data, as requested:

```
col_1               col_2               col_3
location_1          id_1                type_1
location_1          id_1                type_1
location_2          id_1                type_1
location_1          id_2                type_3
location_3          id_3                type_4
```

The goal is to count up the number of unique entries in col_2 given col_1 and col_3. What should appear is:

```
.            type_1    type_2    type_3    type_4
location_1  1             0             1             0
location_2  1             0             0             0 
location_3  0             0             0             0
```

However, the following is returned:

```
.           type_1    type_2    type_3    type_4
location_1  2             0             1             0
location_2  1             0             0             0 
location_3  0             0             0             0
```

Where [1,1] is the offending value in the matrix.

Comment: it would help if you post a sample of your csv

Comment: I can't reproduce your results from that data, and since it's `type_1` instead of `category_1` that can't be the output from that mock-up.  Could you give a self-contained example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a groupby to get at each combination of `col_1` and `col_3`, then unstack to get the `col_3` values as columns:

```
# Copying your data and reading from the clipboard:
df = pd.read_clipboard()

unique_counts = df.groupby(['col_1', 'col_3'])['col_2'].unique().map(len)
unstacked = unique_counts.unstack(level='col_3').fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
unstacked
Out[18]: 
col_3       type_1  type_3  type_4
col_1                             
location_1       1       1       0
location_2       1       0       0
location_3       0       0       1
```